# Disable a cell in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do few calculations and update the result of the same in a cell upon clicking the `Calculate` button (Active X button).

When the Excel sheet is opened, I want few of the cells to be disabled and greyed out. To implement the same, I have written the below lines of code under the `Workbook_Open()` Sub. All the conditions written under the sub are working fine, except, the statement that I have written to disable the cell (written the locked function to disable the cell).

After some surfing, I came to understand that sheet needs to be protected if a cell needs to be disabled/locked. So, I added an extra line in the code to protect the sheet. However, this stopped the result to be updated in a cell.

Upon clicking the calculate button, excel states that the "Sheet is protected". So, is there anyway to enable/ disable the cell using VB Script and without protecting the sheet please?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim b1 As Variant
    Set b1 = Sheets("Calculation Tool").CommandButton22
    b1.Enabled = False

    Range("B4:C4") = ""
    Range("E4:O4") = ""
    Range("E9:F9") = ""

    'This is the code written to disable the cells N4 and O4
    Sheets("Calculation Tool").Range("N4:O4").Locked = True
    Sheets("Calculation Tool").Protect

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot *"disable"* a worksheet cell per-se; it's not like a textbox control.

You ***can***, however:

1. set the cell's fill color to gray (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to enter `Format Cells` > `Fill` tab)
2. lock the cell to prevent changes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to enter `Format Cells` > `Protection` tab)
3. protect the worksheet (`Review` tab > `Protect Sheet`) so the cell locking takes effect.

If you need to change the locked cell you can programmatically unprotect the worksheet, make the change, and then re-protect it. Also note that there are several options available when protecting the worksheet.

Alternatively, you could instead use text boxes, and then [disable/lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/access.textbox.locked) it like you would other controls.

See Also: [**Lock or unlock specific areas of a protected worksheet**](https://support.office.com/article/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-75481b72-db8a-4267-8c43-042a5f2cd93a)

<sub>(Based on your *"greyed-out"* description, I believe you were thinking of textboxes on Microsoft Access Forms.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.. I will try out the given suggestion to see whether my issues is getting resolved

Answer (score 0):

try this code for a range:

Range("A1:B2").Locked = True

Comment: I have tried this out, but, not issue remains persisting. :(